# Highcharts not connecting polar chart ends if first or last value is null

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a polar chart example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/xfvjg7np/1/

If the first value in the series is `null` it will not connect the ends.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            connectNulls: true,
            // First value is null in series
            data: [null, 71.5, null, null, null, null, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Is this a known bug or is there a way to make them connect?

Comment: Hi, I think this is a bug. Here you can find similar topic on Highcharts github. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5416
As a workaround you can add second series and draw the line between first and last point inside this series. http://jsfiddle.net/xfvjg7np/3/

Comment: Thanks. That might have to be the way I'll have to do it for now.